# Counting Regions in the Plane in "Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach"

Tags: algorithm

I am reading the book "Introduction to Algorithms: A Creative Approach".
But got a question about the proof of the formula of Counting Regions in the Plane.

The author use induction to do the proof on page 13 and page 14.

page 13

> Thus, we need only to prove that the presence of nth line causes the (n+1)th line to add one additional region

page 14

> But, the addition of (n+1)th line, when the nth line is present, affects R into two regions(R is cut from two to four regions) instead of just adding one.

It seems that the hypothesis is failed. But

> Hence, the (n+1)th line adds n regions without the presence of nth line, but it adds n+1 regions with nth line, and the proof is complete.

I am really confused.
How can the proof get complete ? 
Does anyone know why ? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.SE

Answer (score 0):

Let's first review the hypothesis:

> Adding one more line to N-1 lines in general position in the plane increases the number of regions by N.

Hypothesis of N is only used when (N)*th*-Line is absent to make sure that (N+1)*th*-Line does increase N regions(of course, when (N)*th*-Line is absent.)

Now we want to go one step forward to the case of N+1.

Here we have the (N)*th*-Line coming back in and check the region *R* and other regions. outside of *R*, how (N)*th*-Line splits a region is not related to (N+1)*th*-Line. (N+1)*th*-Line increases (N-1) lines, exclusive of *R*, no matter how (N)*th*-Line works. Also, because of the presence of (N)*th*-Line, *R* is split in to 4 regions instead of 3, comparing to the original 2 regions. Thus, (N+1)*th*-Line contributes `(N-1) + 2 = N+1` lines.

Notice that when we talk about the region outside of *R*, (N-1) lines increased by (N+1)*th*-Line is promised by the Hypothesis of N. Also, when we talk about Hypothesis of N, only the number of lines matters, rather than which line. Therefore, the hypothesis didn't fail since we use it with the absence of (N)*th*-Line.

Sorry for verbose personal interpretation and hope that can help.

Comment: I think you used the terms lines and regions too freely, making it more confusing. "Thus, (N+1)th-Line contributes (N-1) + 2 = N+1 lines." for one instance

Answer (score 0):

When the nth line is not present, the (n+1)th line adds n regions, and we should notice here that one of the n regions is in the region R where the nth line and the (n+1)th line will intersect. That is to say, without the nth line, the (n+1)th line adds n-1 regions not in R and 1 region in R.

Now if we add back the nth line, we'll create two more regions (one is "additional" as described by Manber) in R and other regions are not affected by the nth line, so we have n-1 + 2 = n+1 newly added regions in total. The induction hypothesis holds.